# What's the fastest and most intuitive way to transfer and install an Android application from a PC?

Tags: applications, installation

I need an Android app to be installed on my phone. I have the APK on my PC. How can I receive it without manually transferring it over USB or using the adb install method. Preferably via WiFi.

Comment: Do you not have a cable or something? All ways I can think of are more or less complicated compared to ADB install.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the file over with something like Pushbullet. It has some file size limitations, which I don't remember right now, but if it's small enough it's a very useful application to do that sort of thing with.

Answer (score 0):

Google [`android wifi transfer`](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+wifi+transfer)

There are plenty of options.